# NDK - Failed to Link C shared library libopusenc

Tags: c, cmake, android-ndk, opus, android.mk

My project consists of 4 static libraries (.a) and I am trying to link them using `cmakelist`. But let's focus on the 2 problematic libraries.

The libraries used in the project: libogg, libopus, libopusenc and libopusfile. The problem is to link libopus into libopusenc.

The script works fine with an outdated artifact from another developer, just when I compile it using the script below it fails.

I am not experienced in makefile or C compilation in general.

First of all, I am getting this error:

```
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86 opus}
  ninja: Entering directory `/Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86'
  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/opus.dir/opus_jni.c.o
  [2/2] Linking C shared library /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libopus.so
  FAILED: /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libopus.so 
  : && /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang --target=i686-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libopus.so -o /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libopus.so CMakeFiles/opus.dir/opus_jni.c.o  -landroid /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/src/main/cpp/opus/lib/x86/libopusenc.a /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/src/main/cpp/opus/lib/x86/libopus.a /Users/user/Repository/opus-android/opus-sample/opus-android/src/main/cpp/opus/lib/x86/libogg.a -llog -latomic -lm && :
  ./libopusenc/src/opusenc.c:242: error: undefined reference to 'opus_projection_encode_float'
  ./libopusenc/src/opusenc.c:245: error: undefined reference to 'opus_multistream_encode_float'
  ./libopusenc/src/opusenc.c:242: error: undefined reference to 'opus_projection_encode_float'
  ./libopusenc/src/opusenc.c:245: error: undefined reference to 'opus_multistream_encode_float'
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? It's probably simple, maybe I am missing something in the `Android.mk`.

To compile the static libraries from the source, I wrote an `Android.mk` file like this:

```
ROOT := $(call my-dir)

#####################
### Build libopus ###
#####################
LOCAL_PATH          := $(ROOT)/libopus
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#include the .mk files
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/celt_sources.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/silk_sources.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus_sources.mk

LOCAL_MODULE        := opus

#fixed point sources
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_FIXED)

#ARM build
CELT_SOURCES += $(CELT_SOURCES_ARM)
SILK_SOURCES += $(SILK_SOURCES_ARM)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
$(CELT_SOURCES) $(SILK_SOURCES) $(OPUS_SOURCES)

LOCAL_LDLIBS        := -lm -llog

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/silk \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/silk/fixed \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/celt

LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LOCAL_CFLAGS        += -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT=1 -DDISABLE_FLOAT_API -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -O3 -fno-math-errno
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS      := -DBSD=1
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS      += -ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loops

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

########################
### Build libopusenc ###
########################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH          := $(ROOT)/libopusenc
LOCAL_MODULE        := opusenc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(addprefix ../, $(shell cd $(LOCAL_PATH)/../; \
    find $(LOCAL_PATH)/src -type f -name '*.c'))

LOCAL_LDLIBS        += -llog -lOpenSLES  -logg -lopus -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    := \
$(ROOT)/include \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LOCAL_CFLAGS        += -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT=1 -DDISABLE_FLOAT_API -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -O3 -fno-math-errno

LOCAL_CFLAGS        += -DPACKAGE_NAME='"T-Pro Dictate"'
LOCAL_CFLAGS        += -DPACKAGE_VERSION='"1.0.0"'
LOCAL_CFLAGS        += -DEXPORT=

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS      := -DBSD=1
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS      += -ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loops

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

To link them using the `CMakeLists`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opus)

add_library(lib_ogg STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_ogg PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libogg.a)

add_library(lib_opus STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opus PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopus.a)

add_library(lib_opusenc STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opusenc PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopusenc.a)

add_library(lib_opusfile STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opusfile PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopusfile.a)

add_library(opus SHARED opus_jni.c)

target_include_directories(opus PRIVATE
                           ${distribution_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(opus
                      android
                      lib_opusenc
                      lib_opus
                      lib_ogg
                      log)
```

Structure:

[image: include files]

EDIT 1:

I tried to add this flag on the `Android.mk` file when compiling the `libopusenc`:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := opus
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libOpus #keep trying...
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ogg
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libOgg #keep trying...
```

Didn't work. :(

Comment: `LOCAL_LDFLAGS`/`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` do nothing for `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY`. Static libraries are not linked to anything. I don't think that's the cause of your problem because you're linking them all in your CMakeLists.txt, but adding more things like that certainly won't fix it.

Comment: Where are those missing symbols supposed to be defined? Use `readelf -sW` to verify that they are where you expect them to be.

Comment: The problem has been sorted, the problem was the flag `-DDISABLE_FLOAT_API`, I had to remove this because libopusenc needs uses float. Also added `OPUS_SOURCES += $(OPUS_SOURCES_FLOAT)`.